# How to run a sql statement in php file with a 10 minutes delay?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = "update place1 set status=2 where car='$wait_value'";
$result=mysqli_query($connect,$query);
```

Need a ten minutes delay here, how's that possible?

```
$query2 = "update place1 set status=1 where car='$wait_value'";
result2=mysqli_query($connect,$query2);
```

Comment: You are looking for a job queue system.

Comment: thanks, but it's not possible to use sleep() for such long situation, do you have any other solution?

Comment: job queue? I don't know what you meant. I just want to make a time lag of around ten minutes after updating the first statement.

Comment: Why do you say it's not possible?  Does `sleep(600)` do something different?  If so, you'll need to post a [mcve] so we can see what's happening.

Comment: @TobySpeight Sorry, I didn't meant that. It'll make a long time to run my php file and will get expired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sleep, but if it's a web app that's not going to work. Try a MySQL event instead:

```sql
CREATE EVENT place_event
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
DO
    update place1 set status=1 where car=?
```

Note that I've used a prepared statement here to bind a parameter to `?`; the code you have (using string concatenation) is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: When I invoke my php file, the first two statements will execute in normal way, and my need is to run the second set of statements after a ten minutes delay.

Comment: yes, exacty what this does. Replace your simple update statement (the second one) with this

Comment: yes, I done this. But still it's exceeding the maximum execution time.

Comment: Well if you schedule a task you need to remove the sleep!

Comment: glad to have been of help. All the best with your project

Answer (score 2):

**Sleep is a VERY bad idea**. Client browser would have to wait 10 minutes to finish request!!!

In my opinion it's not possible to do it like you want to.

You should create another script which queries database and checks if there is new data (and on successful fetch does the job). This script should be run by **cron** every 10 minutes.

[How to create cron job using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php)